# Laravel Spatie Cache Dynamic Web Site and showing new added content (like blog posts etc..)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am using [spatie/laravel-responsecache](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-responsecache) with my laravel app, when I add some new posts on my website, I dont see the new added post anywhere (on homepage, in posts index page listed).

Why I dont see new added posts?! And how to solve this.

I want to have cached homepage and all index pages but to see new added posts, articles etc?!

What is solution for this ?!

Thanks

I installed laravel spatie....

How to see new added content in dynamic website when using laravel spatie...

Comment: After you add a new post, you need to clear the cache of any pages where you want to see the updated data.

Comment: @Aken Roberts,

Yea I understand to do it manually but how to do it automatically by application to recognize when data is added updated and than to clear the cache for that route?

Comment: @Aken Roberts,

And second:

My concern is VIEW AND SHOW blade files. I explained everything here in this uploaded screenshot below what I need, spatie cache work well, site is fast and good but I have for example on some view blade pages some dynamic data 1 or 2 divs with dynamic data. – Tarik S.

  
See this: See this screenshot : imgur.com/a/GXPkvQg ;;"" I want to cache everything on this page (banners in header, navbar, head, footer, everything) except this div (Services) because this is only DYNAMIC on this page. That is what I ask you for...""

Comment: @Aken Roberts,  I want to Cache partials in laravel blade for example just some partials im blade.php where foreach loop is.. that is it...